# I power off the machine and afterwords it reboots

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 and when I shut down my ubuntu it powers on without pressing the power-on button. Can anyone have a solution to why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal window, write this down;

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/rc.local.shutdown
```

the command will open the file /etc/rc.local.shutdown

Then type this command in the file;

```
rmmod ehci_hcd
```

Save the file